# Practicing OOP apprentice in python

Tags: python, oop

I am learning and practicing OOP in Python, doing some exercise from MIT programme. I started with this part that would calculate the number of months needed to pay a downpayment on a house. I am getting this error: 'House_hunting' object has no attribute 'number_of_months'.

```
class House_hunting:

    def __init__(self, total_cost, portion_saved, annual_salary):
        self.total_cost = (total_cost)
        self.portion_saved = float(portion_saved)
        self.annual_salary = (annual_salary)

        portion_down_payment = (self.total_cost)*0.25
        currentsavings = 0
        r = 0.04
        monthly_salary = (self.annual_salary)/12
        number_of_months = 0

        if currentsavings < portion_down_payment:
            savings = currentsavings*r/12 + monthly_salary*float(self.portion_saved)
            number_of_months = number_of_months + 1
        else:
            print(number_of_months)

a = House_hunting(1000000, 0.10, 120000)
print(a.number_of_months())
```

Comment: You have a local variable called `number_of_months` inside `__init__`, but it is not an attribute (nor a method) of your House_hunting object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object does not have an attribute `number_of_months`, as stated in your error message. At the moment your Class only has a variable that's used in the initialisation, but is then discarded. To save the calculated number of months, you should adapt your code, so it looks somewhat like this.

```py
class House_hunting:

    def __init__(self, total_cost, portion_saved, annual_salary):
        self.total_cost = (total_cost)
        self.portion_saved = float(portion_saved)
        self.annual_salary = (annual_salary)

        portion_down_payment = (self.total_cost)*0.25
        currentsavings = 0
        r = 0.04
        monthly_salary = (self.annual_salary)/12
        self.number_of_months = 0

        if currentsavings < portion_down_payment:
            savings = currentsavings*r/12 + monthly_salary*float(self.portion_saved)
            self.number_of_months = self.number_of_months + 1
        else:
            print(self.number_of_months)

a = House_hunting(1000000, 0.10, 120000)
print(a.number_of_months)
```

Also note that the `()` are not needed, since you directly access the attribute, and do not call a function.

Comment: Thank you. Now works! nevertheless i still have a problem with the loop, bcz i am getting one months for down payment. so, i am working to solve it out. if you had saw  another error in my code, i will aprecciete if you tell me.